# Hybris Backoffice results showing No Entries

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I have created a model and imported data to it using impex, data is available when I searched using flexible query in HAC. But when I searched the model in Backoffice, it is displaying as No Entries. No ACCESS or user group assigned.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Under System > Search and Navigation > Facet Search Configurations, try to run full indexing for "Solr Config for Backoffice".

Comment: I did this, but still no entries

Comment: @PriyaS What type is this? Is a custom type that extends Product?

Comment: Yes its a custom type that extends Products. And I have created few attributes inside this type whose modifier is  <modifiers dontOptimize="true" /> Is this creating issue ?

Comment: @PriyaS I don't think it should matter. When there's no results in backoffice, it's usually because the backoffice wasn't indexed yet. Have you checked the logs if there are other errors?

Comment: Hi @PriyaS , Please check in advance blank search, If you getting the result ,It means there is no issue with data, you need to follow the steps given by  geffchang

Comment: @RaushanKumar yes advance blank search is giving results.

Comment: okay, then the issue is only with solr now plz perform full index for backoffice