# Hybris Backoffice not reflecting real Database values

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

In my hybris database I have currently more than 500 products, If I make a Flexible search query in HAC I can see all of them, however, if I go to Backoffice I don't see any. Is there any sync problem?

Comment: I think you have the same issue as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67504531/hybris-backoffice-results-showing-no-entries Could you try my answer there, and let me know if it worked?

Comment: It didn't worked, I think that I may be a cache issue

Comment: Is your Solr up and running? Is there a core for Backoffice?

Comment: @Nexussim Lements Clear your cache in HAC and check again